# How to make textview output the same as a multilined edittext?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, line-breaks, multiline

I have an EditText on an activity that is for multilined comments. I then store this value into a database, which on a ListView activity I use a custom cursor adapter to show the value again.

```
bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
...
TextView comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_comment);
comment.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COMMENTS")));
...
}
```

example EditText value:

```
//user input into EditText
line 1
line 2
line 3

//stored value
line 1\nline 2\nline 3

//TextView
line 1
```

However when testing, upon opening the ListView only the first line of the comments TextView is visible. I have used multiple Log.v to verify that the line breaks ("\n") are there yet I can still only read the first line. On another stackoverflow thread, I saw that one solution was to do this:

```
bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
...
TextView comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_comment);
String temp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COMMENTS"));
comment.setText(temp.replace("\\n", "\n"));
...
}
```

However, the result is still only the first line of the comment (see above). Anyone know any other solution?

Edit: here's a shortened version of the listitem.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1">

        ...

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Comments: "
            android:id="@+id/textView_raybae"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_out"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Thoughts"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:id="@+id/textView_comment"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_out"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_raybae"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView_raybae" />

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post ListView item layout as well

Comment: added a condensed listitem.xml

Comment: android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_raybae"   Try removing that and see what happens.  Its constraining the height of your text view, and possibly preventing it from going multiline

Comment: won't removing that cause the textview to go to the top left corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_raybae"
```

This line in combination with

```
android:layout_below="@+id/textView_out"
```

causes size of your `textView_comment` strict between bottom lines of thus TextViews. Try to delete:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_raybae"
```

and change

```
android:layout_below="@+id/textView_out"
```

to

```
android:layout_below="@+id/textView_raybae"
```

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine  try to replace

```
temp.replace("\\n", "\n")

to

replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"))
```

check using view hierarchy if your view have enough space to render other lines.To debug i would suggest first fix your text view lines e.g (android:lines="2") and see result.

Comment: nope. although i did slightly change the code to be: final String commentS = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COMMENTS")).replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator")); but that shouldn't change anything relating to line breaks